# Finding duplicate data in MySQL database using wildcard

Tags: mysql, sql, database, duplicates, wildcard

I am struggling to create a working query that will search for possible duplicate data in out database.

Using conventional methods doesn't work as the data that looks like this 123456 and 123 456 should be considered the same.

Please can you guys help me in writing up a query that will search for these kinds of duplicates.

The data is all in one field lets call it 'number'.

```
Sample data: 
id                    | number
0                     | 123456
1                     | 124355
2                     | 123432
3                     | 123 456

Expected output:
id               | number
0                | 123456
3                | 123 456
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: please share sample data and your expected output

Comment: Is space the only problem or are there other scenarios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace the spaces eg:

```
  select replace(number, ' ', '')  , count(*)
  from my_table 
  group by replace(number, ' ', '')
```

and for obtain the rows filter the result having count(*) > 1

```
select * from my_table m 
inner join (
  select replace(number, ' ', '') my_val , count(*)
  from my_table 
  group by my_val
  having count(*) > 1

) t on  t.my_val = m.replace(number, ' ', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest an alternative solution which use the replace trick used from @scaisEdge in its right answer.

```
SELECT 
  a.id, a.number, b.id as dup_id, b.number as dup_number 
FROM 
  mytable a,
  mytable b
WHERE
  a.id <> b.id and
  a.number = replace(b.number, ' ', '');
```

This produce a "report" to identify which is the "source" value and the "duplicated" one.

I've created this [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4dd0db/2) to experiment the two approaches .